# Dropzone Rails error after upload: Gallery#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropzone.js

My Galleries#create:

```
def create
    @gallery = Gallery.new(gallery_args)

    if @gallery.save!
      redirect_to :back
    end
end
```

And the error which appears under the uploaded photo thumb with red:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in GalleriesController#create

param is missing or the value is empty: gallery
```

Does know anyone how to fix it?

**UPDATE**

```
def gallery_args
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:image)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add strong parameters to your controller

```
private
  def gallery_params
    params.require(:gallery).permit(:gallery)
  end
```

Comment: I have this def. I add it to the question. But the same thing. Anything else?

Comment: Is image defined in your schema and is it a column in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have paramName specified in your Dropzone initialization ?

Example in coffeescript:

```
dropzone = new Dropzone 'form#new_upload',
  paramName: "upload[image]"
  ...
```